# Perché si dice "l'esame è andato bene" ed "è andata bene"?

Tags: verbs, gender

Ho iniziato un tandem qualche tempo fa e la ragazza che aiuto nella pratica dell'italiano mi ha chiesto come mai si dice

> l'esame è **andato** bene

ma invece

> è **andata** bene

quando si parla in generale di qualcosa.

Io non so proprio spiegarmi perché quando si parla in generale si dica "è andata bene/ male". Perché usare il femminile? A cosa si allude?

Comment: Non metto una risposta perché sono tutt'altro che sicuro. Potrebbe esserci "la cosa" sottinteso.

Comment: La *prova* è andata bene.

Comment: Comunque dipende molto anche dalla domanda: ad una richiesta del tipo "Com'è andato l'esame?" la risposta sarebbe "È andato bene".

Comment: @black: Giusto, ma l'OP specifica «quando si parla in generale di qualcosa».

Comment: *La faccenda/vicenda/impresa è andata bene*

Comment: Perché sia così non lo so, però ci sono molte altre espressioni "generiche" in cui si usa il femminile: "farla franca", "darla a bere", "farla grossa", "farcela", "legarsela al dito", "prendersela" sono solo le prime che mi vengono in mente.

Answer (score 4):

Nelle costruzioni impersonali il participio o complemento predicativo selezionano un accordo generico, generalmente al maschile: *se non si è ben legati/attenti, si rischia di cadere; ieri è piovuto*.  Deviazioni da questo principio si registrano in **espressioni fisse** come *è fatta!* o *è andata bene!*  ([Fonte](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/))

Il clitico che ricorre qui non ha funzione di rinvio anaforico rispetto a un sintagma nominale. Tuttavia, in alcune espressioni come *farsela addosso, prenderle o darla*, il parlante è in grado di risalire al referente che il pronome indica, anche se non compare nel cotesto precedente. In tal caso il pronome rimanda a oggetti extralinguistici (di solito tabuizzati: le feci o l’urina in *farsela addosso*, le botte in *prenderle*, l’organo genitale femminile in *darla*). In altri casi la referenza del clitico è divenuta opaca; il parlante non è più in grado di individuare l’entità extralinguistica cui ricondurre il clitico oggetto (*finirla, smetterla, piantarla, avercela, prendersela, tirarsela*). ([Fonte](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/oggetto_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/), 3.4 Pronomi oggetto di verbi procomplementari)

Se la ragazza è inglese, [A Reference Grammar of Modern Italian](https://books.google.se/books?id=RszKAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA103) conferma che il femminile nelle espressioni idiomatiche non dovrebbe necessariamente avere senso:
[image]