# “Smetti di” oppure “smettila di”?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

*Ciao a tutti!*

I have a question. I know that “to stop doing something” is *smettere di fare qualcosa*. Nevertheless I’ve heard Italian speakers add the pronoun *la* when using the verb in the imperative mood. So instead of

> Smetti di fare questo!

I hear instead

> Smettila di fare questo!

Is there a reason why the *la* should be there? It doesn’t seem to be doing anything. And why is it feminine (*la*) rather than masculine (*lo*)?

*Grazie in anticipo!*

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @George!

Comment: [This question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/perch%C3%A9-si-dice-lesame-%C3%A8-andato-bene-ed-%C3%A8-andata-bene) and I.M.'s answer to it is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feminine pronoun *la* can be found with several verbs. Its purpose can go from an emphasis of the verb to a complete change of meaning (like in English phrasal verbs).

***Smetterla***, ***finirla*** and ***piantarla*** belong to the first case: they are synonyms and they all mean **to quit** or **to stop** with a strong emphasis. The pronoun stands for a generic *quella cosa* (= that thing), which is feminine.

On the contrary, there are verbs that change their meaning when *la* (with other pronouns) is appended. The following are some examples that come to my mind now:

- ***prendersela*** = to get offended
- ***avercela*** con qualcuno = to be angry with s.o.
- ***farcela*** = to succeed
- ***tirarsela*** = to boast
- ***sentirsela*** = to feel confident (to do s.t.)

In these cases, the pronouns have no own meaning. This is to underline that the case you asked is specific, i.e. it depends on the underlying verb.

Comment: And ***cavarsela***?

Comment: ***Cavarsela*** belong to the second category, and it means "to make it through a tricky situation".

Answer (score 6):

Maybe because:

> smetti*la* = smetti di fare quel*la* cos*a* (stop doing this)

which is related to "la cosa" that is **feminine** in Italian.

The *lo* at the end is used rarely, and it mostly changes the meaning, for example:

If you see two guys fighting and you say to the one of them:

> "Finisci**la**!"

He understands that he has to stop fighting.

But if you say:

> "finisci**lo**!"

He understands that he has to kill (or just to knock-out) the other guy.

EDIT: 
according to [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/oggetto_%28Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano%29/) (in Italian),

> (23) smetti di mangiare
>
> (24) smettila di mangiare

The phrase (24) expresses a higher degree of involvement of the speaker. 
compared to the main form of the verb "smetterla" emphasizes the imperative, conveying even a negative connotation.

Comment: So, if someone said to me *smetti di fumare* they would be telling me to quit smoking over a period of time, whereas if they said *smettila di fumare* that would be telling me to stop smoking right now, put my cigarette out immediately. Am I right?

Comment: not exactly, "smettila di fumare" implies a higher degree of involvement, for example a child say to it's mom: "smettila di fumare, ti prego!" (please stop smoking), it's colloquial language.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in its generality: *smetti di* is very generic, whereas *smettila di* is more specific because of the definite article *la* that represents the object involved.

Let us analyze smoking.

> Smetti di fumare

Here, it largely depends on the situation; for example:

> Smetti di fumare (in generale, nella tua vita) - quit smoking
>   Smetti di fumare (perché in questa stanza è vietato) - stop smoking here, it's forbidden her
>   Smetti di fumare (la pipa, la sigaretta, il sigaro ecc.)

While *Smettila di fumare*:

> Stai fumando la sigaretta? Se sì, *smettila* (*di farlo* is implicit).

---

> Smetti di parlarmi!  (generic; can't use *smettila*)

Comment: I don’t get why *smetti di parlarmi* is generic. What’s the difference between generic and specific?

Comment: @GeorgeLaw It's pretty much the same as the example about _smoking_. It sounds odd; I would either say _smetti di parlarmi_ or _smettila_, but not _smettila di parlarmi_ because it's a bit repetitive. (you're mentioning the act twice)